# React component ignore displaying text for empty obj

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component with a method that reads some data from an object and then returns the text on its status on another component.

The problem is that when the application is loading at first the obj length will be 0 initially and when the object data is loaded it will then
update and the obj.length will be higher than 0.

The what happens is this:

```
Scenario 1 (obj will actually have data) 
      -- App Loading
      -- getTxt checks if obj is empty
      -- As data is not loaded yet on the first call obj.length will return 0 so 'No Data Found' is displayed
      -- Then when the app finishes loading it then updates and the obj.length > 0 so 'Found the data' is displayed
```

or

```
Scenario 2 (obj will be empty) 
      -- App Loading
      -- getTxt checks if obj is empty
      -- As data is not loaded yet on the first call obj.length will return 0 so 'No Data Found' is displayed
      -- Then when the app finishes loading it then updates and the obj is actually empty so it can stay the same.
```

My problem is that if after the app is loaded and obj.length re-checked it returns > then 0 then I don't want to display the first 'No Data Found',
but I need to have the condition just in case after the app has finished loading the data the data is still = 0

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'


class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    getTxt() {

        if (this.props.obj.length > 0) {
            return 'Found the data';
        } else if (this.props.obj.length == 0) {
            return 'No Data Found';
        }

            return 'Searching Data'
        }



    render() {
        return <SomeComponent text={this.getTxt()}/>
    }
}


export {MyComponent}
```

What can I do in order to get this done?

Comment: So you really have three states (data not loaded, data loaded and empty, data loaded and not empty) that you are trying to represent through two values (length === 0 or length > 0). That cannot work. Introduce a new value: If `this.props.obj` is `null`, then the data hasn't be fetched yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

It sounds like you don't want to render anything until the data is received?

What I do when I need to do this is use component state to keep track of loading status. When the component mounts, set `state.loading` to true.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({loading: true})
}
```

Set loading to false once everything is updated.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    this.setState({loading: false})
  }
}
```

And in the `render` function, conditionally render based on loading state.

```
render() {
    const text = this.state.loading ? "Loading..." : this.getTxt()
    return <SomeComponent text={text}/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments by Felix Kling.

You have three different states.

1. Initial state
2. No data
3. There is some data

Initial state will have the `data` props set to `null`. After the data was received it could be an empty object `{}` or an object with some information.

I would probably write this in the following way:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  getStatus() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (data === null) {
      return "Searching data"
    }
    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
      return "No data was found"
    }
    return "Found some data"
  }

  render() {
    return <SomeComponent text={this.getStaus()}/>
  }
}
```

This is almost perfect because I would like to separate logic from the view. I will have a reducer that will get the data and upon its values/length it will determine the status.

```
const statusReducer = (data) => {
  if (data === null) {
    return "Searching data"
  }
  if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
    return "No data was found"
  }
  return "Found some data"
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { data: null }
  componentDidMount() {
    getData()
      .then(resp => resp.json)
      .then(resp => this.setState({data: resp.data})
  }
  render() {
    return <SomeComponent text={statusReducer(this.state.data)} />
  }
}
```

You may ask what's the point of passing this to another function (`reducer`)? First, as I mentioned, separating the logic from the view. Second, `statusReducer` can be reused in other components. Third, easier to test the code.

**NOTE**: We only took care of the happy path. However, if there was a problem with the request or the response contains error, we probably get the wrong status.

To handle such case lets look at a different approach. Lets have `data` and `status` in `state`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { data: null, status: 'PENDING' }
  componentDidMount() {
    getData()
      .then(resp => resp.json)
      .then(resp => this.setState({data: resp.data, status: 'COMPLETE'})
      .catch(err => this.setState(data: err.Message, status: 'ERROR'})
  }
  render() {
    switch(this.state.status) {
    case 'COMPLETE':
      return <SomeComponent text={statusReducer(this.state.data)} />
    case 'ERROR':
      return <ErrorComponent message={this.state.data} />
    case 'PENDING':
      return <Spinner />
    default:
      // there is a runtime/compiling error. 
      // Notify it in you console.log or something
      return null // Here I am silently failing but that's not a good practice
    }
  }
}
```

We could do even better if we move the `switch-case` statement to another function and call it `loadReducer`. But I will let you decide whether to do it or not.

Please notice Eitan's solution too. He uses both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUpdate` to update `status`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Felix in the comments. You may be better off with a nested ternary in a functional component. The component should update whenever props to it `obj` are updated.

```
export const myComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <SomeComponent 
      text={ props.obj ?
        props.obj.length > 0 ?
              'Found Data'
            :
              'No Data Found'
          : 
            'Searching'
      }
    />
  )
}
```